# Flutter on Chromebook

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I tried to get flutter running on my Lenovo Duet Chromebook. Unfortunately, I got

```
$ flutter doctor -v
~/apps/flutter/bin/internal/shared.sh: line 228: ~/apps/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux penguin 5.4.119-14945-gafc97d54f809 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Aug 10 21:44:33 PDT 2021 aarch64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

How is it possible to flutter running?

Thank you in advance,